# Cannot instantiate type

Tags: java, spring-mvc, generics

I need some help on this code. I am not sure how I write this particular line.
I have this class:

```
public class MyController<T extends MyModel> extends AnotherController {

    // Taking xModel and copies properties to YModel

    private T myModel(T xModel) {
        T yModel = new T();
        copyMyProperties(yModel, xModel);
        return yModel;
    }

}
```

at `T()`, I am getting "cannot instantiate type T". Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.